# When using higher order terms in multivariable regression what is the effect on the P-value

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value

I have a large dataset, lets say 500 lines of data. As a quick workaround to higher order regression I've made educated guesses about what higher order terms I would expect in my regression equation. I've then included these as separate variables in my linear regression. For example:

```
x(1) = x(1)
x(2) = x(2)
x(3) = x(3)
x(4) = x(1)^2
x(5) = x(1)*x(2)
```

etc.

My question is since I can get a t stat and hence a P-value for each of these x(1) - x(5) how do I judge the significance of x(1) since x(1) is a component of x(4) and x(5). Or can I treat them as separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat them separately, with caveat that usually when higher order terms are added, the lower order terms are preserved too. For instance, if x(4) is significant while x(1) is not, you keep both variables in the model. This is not the strict rule, but doing otherwise usually leads to problems later.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've actually made this error already! So since I have omitted x(1) and kept x(4) what sort of problems might I encounter? I've got an R^2 value of 0.995 and all my p values are very close to zero.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg, it's not always an error. A useful way to think about this is through Taylor expansion. Most functions have the first order derivative not zero. By omitting x(1) you are making a statement about your true model relationship. It is not necessarily a wrong statement, of course, but it is very strong.

Comment: Thank you. That comment made this a complete answer for me!